# $http.post Angular POST

Tags: angularjs, http, post

Intentando conectarme a un API desde angular y me sale el siguiente error:

```
   XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://web/api/beta/ruc. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

el codigo es el siguiente ...

```
  var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("HttpController", function ($scope, $http, $httpParamSerializer) {

    $scope.GetData = function () {
        var data = $httpParamSerializer({
            token : "c664bfba-9969-4e57-ab7a-4532bc81670b-ef3868a6-e62f-45c8-9a36-92db7c21a353",
            ruc : "10178520739"
        });
        var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;'
            }
        }

        $http.post('https://web/api/beta/ruc', data, config)
        .then(function (data) {
            $scope.response = "Exito" + data;
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            $scope.response = "Error: " + data;
        });
    };

});
```

si quieren el ejemplo mas detallado y la web a la cual realizo el API pueden acceder a https://jsfiddle.net/darthSinuhe/ckby0x88/

Comment: Este es un problema de cors, te dejo este link que detalla más al respecto https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 4):

Imagínate que tu aplicación Angular, con dirección `https://web/...`, en lugar de pedir datos al servicio con dirección `http://localhost:3000`, pidiera datos a un servicio con dirección `https://mail.google.com`... ahora piénsalo con cuidado... ¿Debería el navegador permitir que la aplicación angular acceda a esos datos?... ¿No sería muy fácil leer el correo de cualquier persona sin siquiera conocer sus credenciales?

Esto es **CORS**, una característica de los navegadores, que sirve para evitar que una pagina no autorizada acceda a los datos de un servicio X.

Osea que es **el servicio** quien autoriza o no a otras paginas a consumir dicho servicio.

CORS funciona gracias a la familia de headers HTTP que comienzan con `Access-Control`. Hay varios grados de libertad para configurar el origen, el/los métodos HTTP (GET, POST, etc), el Content-Type, Headers, etc.

La solución es habilitar CORS en el endpoint (`http://localhost:3000`), en las respuestas deberías ver algo así..

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

**Para habilitar CORS, como depende del server que uses, te dejo este enlace que da un resumen de como hacerlo en los servers mas comunes: http://enable-cors.org/server.html**

**Ojo!!** esto significa que **cualquier pagina** web tendrá la posibilidad de consumir este servicio. Así que dependiendo de la sensibilidad de la información quizá debas poner una regla mas especifica.

Answer (score 1):

```
var config = {
    headers : {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8;'
    }
};
$http.get("controller/getPositionAutority.php,config)
   .success(function (response){
         console.log(response);
})
```

Es necesario enviar los `headers` al *Api* para que te responda o como en este ejemplo declarar los `headers` de respuesta por defecto como objeto JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Es un problema de Cors. Tienes que configurar la API para que acepte estas peticiones. Para ello prueba a acceder al fichero Startup.cs de tu API.

1- En el método ConfigureServices() añade la lĺinea: 
services.AddCors();

[image: ConfigureServices]

2- En el método Configure() añade:
  app.UseCors(
    builder => builder
     .AllowAnyOrigin()
     .AllowAnyMethod()
     .AllowAnyHeader()
     .AllowCredentials()
  );
[image: Configure]